# how to reference a macro list in a filter of sas query editor

Tags: sql, filter, sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

Hello Stackoverflow community.

I need to insert a filter into SAS Enterprise Guide query builder.

This filter should contain a huge list of product codes, the format of this column is a character, but it's very time consuming to insert them one by one into the filter section using the IN operator.

So I was thinking to create a sas macrovariable, and referencing it into the filter of the query builder. Below an example

```
%LET product_codes = 
'815001004490'
'815300465351',
'815100001069',
'815000000152',
'815100000561'
;
```

I wrote a proc sql to check if the program was giving me back results, and I got what I was expecting

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select * from library_name.table_name
where product in (&product_codes.)
;
quit;
```

However, when I repeat the same process in SAS query editor, then I get back an empty table.
[image]

I guess I am missing something. I am aware that the macrovariable works as simple text generator. How can this be resolved? any ideas? what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Try adding the parenthesis in the Values box, `(&product_codes.)`. Also, include the code generated may help to see what's going wrong, but I suspect it's just the missing `()`

Comment: Does the tool you are using allow you to see the SAS code it generated?  Or at least the SAS log?

Comment: I tried this with sashelp.cars and got back what I was expecting. Take a look at the generated code. Is it adding quotes around `&product_codes.`? There is an option to disable that.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem.

When I add a filter in SAS query editor, there is a little box below which asks to include or not values between double quotes. by doing that, I came out with a result from my query editor